# Separate builds from localizations

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I want to add localization to my iOS app. I was able to do that via the localization mechanism in XCode and used 'localizable.strings' for each of the 2 locales + localized the UI via storyboard and different ViewControllers.

Thing is I wish to create two separate builds/apps, one from each locale. I don't want it to be a universal app which gets automatically localized according to the user locale settings as I wish to make it available to different countries with different monetization model.

What's the correct way of creating a separate build from each localisation (and not have two versions of the whole project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new target and include the necessary files in each target.  You will have to have different app id's though...

You can specify the "compile sources" for each target though, so you could for example have certain view controllers build to one target, and others to another...

Comment: Yea well, this is the standard _add target_ mechanism, but how do I configure the correct setting so that each target will be localized correctly without duplicating code (using the internal _localize_ Xcode mechanism).